# DelayedConfirmationView on Android X

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx

I used DelayedConfirmationView on an android wear app I am trying to refactor to work for API 22 devices (Lollipop). Is there an equivalence for this on API 22 (Android 5.1)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/DelayedConfirmationView), the androidx equivalent of `DelayedConfirmationView` is [`androidx.wear.widget.CircularProgressLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/widget/CircularProgressLayout)

Answer (score 0):

`DelayedConfirmationView`  is deprecated use the `android.support.wear.widget.CircularProgressLayout` from the Android Support Library Wear module instead.

Comment: `android.support` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/CircularProgressLayout), people should use `androidx`, as per my answer.